# how to declare variable and get result set in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, variables

I have table named Students in PostgreSQL. In that table i have `StudId, StudName` and `Gender` columns. I want to get the number of male and female students in the table in a single result set in a function.

```
StudId   StudName    Gender
101      Peter       M
102      George      M
103      Mary        F
104      Rose        F
```

I already done this with SQL Server and MySQL. But I don't have any idea to do this with PostgreSQL.

I'm newer one to PostgreSQL, someone helps to finds the results. Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two sub-selects like this

```
select (select count(*) cnt_male from tbl where gender='M') 
      ,(select count(*) cnt_female from tbl where gender='F')
```

or

You can use `case` in `count()` function  like this

```
select count(case when gender='M' then 1 end) cnt_male
      ,count(case when gender='F' then 1 end) cnt_female 
from tbl
```

---

Result:

```
cnt_male cnt_female 
-------- ---------- 
2        2
```

---

Edit:

as per op's  [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35144919/revisions)

```
create function fn_gender_cnt() returns table(tot_male bigint,tot_female bigint)
as
$$

  select count(case when gender='M' then 1 end) cnt_male
      ,count(case when gender='F' then 1 end) cnt_female 
from tbl

$$
language sql
```

usage:

```
select * from fn_gender_cnt();
```

result:

```
    tot_male tot_female 
    -------- ---------- 
    2        2
```

Comment: Thank you Friend. I found the logic already, but I don't know how to get the two results in a Function. Sorry for the mistake, now I update the Question.

Comment: @DineshDB I've updated my answer ...added a function to get the counts, is that what you were looking for??

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your help. It works pretty good... Thanks a lot.